# Make a cross account call to Redshift Data API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-redshift

**Summary of problem:**

- We have an AWS Redshift cluster in Account A, this has a database called 'products'
- In Account B we have a lambda function which needs to execute a SQL statement against 'products' using the Redshift Data API
- We have setup a new secret in AWS Secrets manager containing the redshift cluster credentials. This secret has been shared with Account B. We've confirmed Account B can access this information from AWS Secrets Manager.

When we call the Redshift Data API action 'executeStatement' we get the following error:

```
ValidationException: Cluster doesn't exist in this region.
at Request.extractError (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52:27)
at Request.callListeners (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (C:\git\repositories\sandbox\redshift\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

The error message suggest it's perhaps not going to the correct account, since the secret contains this information I would have expected it to know.

**Code Sample:**

Here's my code:

```js
var redshiftdata = new aws.RedshiftData({ region: 'eu-west-2'});

const params : aws.RedshiftData.ExecuteStatementInput = {
  ClusterIdentifier: '<clusteridentifier>',
  Database: 'products',
  SecretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountNo>:secret:<secretname>',
        Sql: `select * from product_table where id = xxx`,
        StatementName: 'statement-name',
        WithEvent: true
    };

redshiftdata.executeStatement(params, 
    async function(err, data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else {
        const resultParams : aws.RedshiftData.GetStatementResultRequest = { Id: data.Id! };
        redshiftdata.getStatementResult(resultParams, function(err, data){
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
            else     console.dir(data, {depth: null});
        })
    }
});
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to create an assumable role in account A, and use that to invoke the data API. Search this site for "assume role in javascript".

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer Parsifal. Here's a code snippet of the working solution.

```js
import aws from "aws-sdk";

var roleToAssume = {RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<rolename>',
                    RoleSessionName: 'example',
                    DurationSeconds: 900,};

var sts = new aws.STS({ region: '<region>'});

sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function(err, data) {
    if (err) 
    {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else
    {
      aws.config.update({
          accessKeyId: data.Credentials?.AccessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: data.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: data.Credentials?.SessionToken
      })
    
      // Redshift code here...
    }
});
```